# How to rewrite to a page of another domain, in varnish?

Tags: https, url-rewriting, varnish

We have a varnish server, which has the domain: `myserver.com`.

Now I want to configure it to support:

When user visit `https://myserver.com/login`, it will get the content of another website `https://s3.amazonaws.com/myserver/mysite/login/index.html`, and response to user. The url seen by user is still `https://myserver.com/login`.

I'm not sure if this behavior is called `rewrite`, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is varnish support this function? How to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's called pharming. Especially for login pages.

Rewriting works only within your domain. You shouldn't be doing what you're asking about.

Also you'd need to create a backend entry for that other website and then if *req.url* matches with the one you want, change backend with *set req.backend* and *set req.url* to the other one.